# Convex and concave div creation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there way to create a div with convex or concave shape using javascript or CSS3. or any other way out available.

Comment: What do you mean 'convex or concave shape'? Are you trying to create a div with curved vertical edges?

Comment: What do you need it for? You could use `canvas` and draw whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Chris, curved vertical edges are not my concern but ya, a curve in the horizontal edges of the div does make a lot of difference. Please suggest me something on this. And Sergie, i don't wanna use canvas for this.

Comment: Hey Sergie, can u show me a sample for this using canvas??

Answer (score 2):

You can get convex and concave shapes using CSS3 border-radius.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/cogent/6A5Lb/

To get this working in older versions of IE, you can use CSS3 PIE - http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Sure it is. You can set the background color of the overlaying shapes to match the underlying background color.. the OP did not require transparency around the shape.

Comment: No... a truly concave shape would not have a transparency issue (http://jsfiddle.net/8fxdmf9k/). These shapes just give the impression of concavity, but actually it's one convex shape drawn overtop another convex shape.

Comment: If you don't need transparency, this is a great option and I don't see a compelling list of alternative answers. If you need transparency, this solution does not work. That doesn't make the shape generated not concave.

Comment: Ok... Technically true, though a disappointing result when searching for a truly concave (single) shape.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsfiddle that shows how to do a convex polygon:
http://jsfiddle.net/jafka/

You use this thing called "slant". It's a css trick using borders.
You can use the same principles to build a concave polygon.

You can read more at:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html

http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/slantinfo.html

Comment: **Convex** and **concave** polygons. Not *just* polygons. The question has some ambiguity to it, but I don't think this would be what he meant.

Comment: Hi diofeher, i m trying to create a div with convex curve using CSS3 and javascript only. By a convex curve i mean, a div which starts flat from and bulges out till the center and then begins to get flat towards its right end. If there is a wayout, can u plz guide me on that.

Comment: Diofeher, this isn't what i m expecting. My requirement is to have a single div which "BULGES" out at the center in a smooth way to give a feel that its convex. Similar to how a convex lens looks.